# Xamarin.Forms: CurrentPlatform is inaccessible in Android project

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to use Azure Mobile Client with Android. But, when I add the line
`Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.CurrentPlatform.Init();`
in the `MainActivity`, it says that `CurrentPlatform` is inaccessible. It's funny, because in the same solution I have this line in iOS project.

Image 1
[image]

Image 2
[image]

Image 3
[image]

Image 4
[image]

Please, could you help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the steps mentioned here.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-client/issues/408

Now it's working.